# Trouble understanding transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations

This problem comes from the transposition area of the Wikipedia page for symmetric group ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Transpositions)).

We have $g=(1 2 5)(3 4)$. It then says that g can also be written as $(1 2)(2 5)(3 4)$, but I don't understand why. I follow why g sends 1 to 2, 2 to 5, 3 to 4, 4 to 3, and 5 to 1 under its original representation. But under the second representation, wouldn't 5 go to 2? I can slightly follow that 5 going to 2 means it goes to 1, but then why doesn't 2 to go to 1, but instead it goes to 5?

Comment: I understand your confusion. Some authors write composition from left to right, others from right to left. Here, they use the convention that composition is done from right to left, while you do it the other way.  However, what you write is still wrong, regardless the convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what the composition $(12)(25)(34)$ does to each number:
$$
1 \overset{(34)}{\to} 1 \overset{(25)}{\to} 1 \overset{(12)}{\to}2\\
2 \overset{(34)}{\to} 2 \overset{(25)}{\to} 5 \overset{(12)}{\to}5\\
3 \overset{(34)}{\to} 4 \overset{(25)}{\to} 4 \overset{(12)}{\to}4\\
4 \overset{(34)}{\to} 3 \overset{(25)}{\to} 3 \overset{(12)}{\to}3\\
5 \overset{(34)}{\to} 5 \overset{(25)}{\to} 2 \overset{(12)}{\to}1
$$
Note that, just as in the composition of functions, our transpositions are applied from right to left.

Comment: Even if the composition was performed from left to right, the OP made mistakes.

Comment: I understand my mistake now! I was treating 2 as if it was still 2 when I applied $(1 2)$, but it's 5 at that point.

Comment: @Leonhard there you go, glad we could sort that out.

Answer (score 2):

$(12)(25)(34)$ is read right to left. So $3$ goes to $4$, $4$ goes to $3$, $2$ goes to $5$, $5$ goes to $2$ which then goes to $1$ and $1$ goes to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since notations can change across books, perhaps you may want to see how [transposition product is introduced on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Transpositions).

> ## Transpositions
>
> $$(a~b~c~d~\ldots ~y~z)=(a~b)\cdot (b~c~d~\ldots ~y~z)$$
>   This means the initial request is to move $a$ to $b$, $b$ to $c$, $y$ to $z$ and finally $z$ to $a$. Instead one may roll the elements keeping $a$ where it is by ***executing the right factor first***.

In this case, $(3~4)$ is independent from $(1~2~5)=(1~2)(2~5)$.

Mneumonic skill: you may find it easy to remember that on the RHS, we are just writing the *same* element twice across the dot sign, and *keep the order unchanged*.